# How to link react-hook-form and react-input-mask?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, input-mask

Here is the code, but with this linking method, an error appears:

```
<IMaskInput
    type='text'
    mask={reGex}
    lazy={false}
    placeholder="Фамилия"
    unmask={true}
    value={lastName}
    onAccept={ (event) => handlerLastName(event) }
>
    {(register) => (
       <input
          {...register("lastName", {
                required: true,
                minLength: {
                     value: 2,
                     message: "*Минимум 2 символа"
                },
                maxLength: {
                     value: 30,
                     message: "*Не больше 30 символов"
                },
                onChange: (event) => handlerLastName(event.target.value)
          })}
       />
     )}
</IMaskInput>
```

With this binding method, React throws an error with a child element:

```
Uncaught Error: input is a void element tag and must neither have `children` nor use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`.
```